# Permanent (non-hiding) drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to present a different view depending on MediaQuery output. Hiding/sliding drawer on smaller devices like phones and a permanent/docked drawer on larger devices like tablets.

I see that drawer is part of the Scaffold but the existing infrastructure does not allow for a permanent drawer, or at least I don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is create a different layout for tablets since the drawer will opaque de view when is it open. So create a new widget for the drawer (it will be used in both screens) then check the width of it and depending of the size, put it as the drawer parameter or inside the body, within a stack

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
      drawer: size.width < 500 ? Drawer() : null,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          if (size.width >= 500) Drawer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```